# No module _cffi_ freezing with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, paramiko, cx-freeze

I am developing a PySide application (Qt for Python) and I would like to freeze it using cx_Freeze.

When I run `python setup.py build` using my setup file below, it creates the build directory without errors, but then when I run the .exe file generated, I get the error message shown below:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable 

target = Executable(
    script="main_window.py",
    base = "Win32GUI",
    icon="images\\icon.ico"
    )

setup(name = "DemiurgoXMLgen" , 
    version = "0.1" , 
    description = "" ,
    options={'build_exe': {'include_files': ['images\\']}},
    executables = [target])
```

[image]

I think it has something to do with the **Paramiko** package I am using in my application. Has anyone encountered and solved this problem?

Comment: Please post the error message as text, not as an image, see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/8516269)

Comment: Yeah I know, I posted it like this because windows wouldn't let me copy it as text :(

Comment: Yeah I know, then you need to type, which is annoying... or use e.g. [Console2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/console/), which allows you to select and copy text :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it by modifying `setup.py` as below:

```
import os.path

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
build_exe_options = {"include_files" : [
    os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, "DLLs", "libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll"),
    os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, "DLLs", "libssl-1_1-x64.dll")]}
build_exe_options = {"packages": ['cffi', 'cryptography'], 'include_files': ['images\\', os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, "DLLs", "libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll"),
    os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, "DLLs", "libssl-1_1-x64.dll")]}

target = Executable(
    script="main_window.py",
    base = "Win32GUI",
    icon="images\\icon.ico"
    )

setup(name = "DemiurgoXMLgen" , 
    version = "0.1" , 
    description = "" ,
    options={'build_exe': build_exe_options},
    executables = [target])
```

and modifying in `paramiko->ed25519key.py` the import:

<s>from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend</s>

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import openssl as openssl_backend
```

Essentially:

1. explicitly specify the import of `cffi` and `cryptography` in `build_exe_options`
2. copy the *dlls* for `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dl`l and `libssl-1_1-x64.dll`
3. explicitly specify the backend as `openssl_backend` instead of `default_backend`